# How to check the process tree in HP-UX, just like ptree in Solaris?

Tags: process, ps, hp-ux

How do I check the process tree in HP-UX, just like ptree in Solaris ?

Answer (score 0):

HP-UX has a `ptree` utility ([HP-UX PDF man page](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c02267723/c02267723.pdf), [Solaris man page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/ptree-1.html#scrolltoc)).

Comment: I have B.11.11 but no /usr/bin/ptree. Will check with sysadmin.